# .htaccess to modify constantly changing url

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Im fronting a problem of long-file-url and what may seem
suspicious to some users.

So how to .htaccess that url:
http://file.domainame.com/public.php?service=files&t=bacd1ed488

to this:
http://domainame.com/bacd1ed488

?

everything else is static except 10 char unique hash, what is generated.

Comment: What have you tried? There are some examples in the "related" sidebar on the right of this page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 - Put this code in your `root/mainsite/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /public.php?service=files&t=$1 [L,QSA]
```

2 - Put this code in your `root/file/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+public\.php\?service=files&t=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://domain.com/%1? [R=302,L]
```

Comment: Hi! it worked out well, but it did not remove file. before domainame.com

Comment: Are `file.domain.com` and `domain.com` on same host and sharing same DocumentRoot? Also tell me which full URI didn't work?

Comment: Ty for your response!
They are on same host, document system looks like this: `root/mainsite -> responds to domainame.com` and `root/file -> responds to file.domainame.com`

Comment: ok check updated code. This goes into 2 different .htaccess files

Answer (score 0):

**The original URL:**

```
http://file.domainame.com/public.php?service=files&t=bacd1ed488
```

**The rewritten URL**

```
http://file.domainame.com/bacd1ed488
```

**The .htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /public.php?service=files&t=$1 [L]
```